# Java - Intellij IDEA warns about NPE in enum getter method lambda

Tags: java, intellij-idea, enums, nullpointerexception, warnings

I have following enum:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Maps;

public enum ServiceType {
    SOME_SERVICE (4, SomeServiceEntity.class);

    private int id;
    private Class<? extends ServiceEntity> entityClass;

    private static final Map<Integer, ServiceType> LOOKUP = Maps.uniqueIndex(
            Arrays.asList(ServiceType.values()),
            ServiceType::getId     <<=======
    );

    ServiceType(int id, Class<? extends ServiceEntity> entityClass) {
        this.id = id;
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    // and other methods....
}
```

This line of code marked by Intellij IDEA as:

> Method reference invocation 'ServiceType::getId' may produce
>   'java.lang.NullPointerException'

How is this possible while I have the only constructor which include my `id` field and enum is static list of objects so they all suppose to have id?

How can I get rid of this warning?

UPD:
Sticked with:

```
private static final Map<Integer, ServiceType> LOOKUP = Arrays.stream(
        ServiceType.values()).collect(Collectors.toMap(
                ServiceType::getId, Function.identity()
        )
);
```

Comment: `ServiceType::getId` is a method reference with the equivalent lambda expression `st -> st.getId()`. In the latter you see that a NPE could occur.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose sure. But  `serviceType ->  serviceType.getId()` still warns about NPE which I cannot find possibility to happen

Comment: You repeated the same lambda expression that - as I already explained - can possibly throw a NPE. If the argument (in my example `st`) is `null`, then the expression `st.getId()` throws the NPE.

Comment: The static code analysis doesn't look at the values that are actually assigned, it just sees a unsafe method call and thus shows the warning. It's not intelligent enough to see that it won't be null in this case.

Comment: Which version of Intellij do you have? I'm not receiving any warnings about NPE with this code on 2019.1.3...

Comment: @vlumi I actually have older one 2018.2.1. This could be a thing

Comment: @vlumi I'm using 2019.1.3 as well, but it does give me the warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment says, you are using a lambda there, that gets a parameter. And when that one is null, that gives an NPE.

So rather try something like:

```
private static final Map<Integer, ServiceType> LOOKUP = 
  Arrays
    .stream(ServiceType.values())
    .Collectors.toMap(ServiceType::getId, Function. identity());
```

which ... err ... might give you the same kind of warning.

So, if you really want to use stream'ing here, you probably have to suppress that warning.

Comment: IDEA 2019.3 won't give an NPE warning with the sample provided by GhostCat